# Does using Linux OS matter while developing Android apps?

Tags: android, linux, windows, developer-tools

I started Android development and realized that Android is totally built on Linux, but I'm programming on Windows currently.

Shall I continue using Windows or shall I switch to Linux?

Does using Linux matter for a software developer?

Comment: its entirely up to you.but the development will not be effected on either

Comment: Stick with what you know.  It makes no significant difference.  I develop on all 3 (Linux, Windows, OSX) and all have their strengths and weaknesses, in about equal measure for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked in Samsung Mobile division on Android Smartphones Device Driver. I haven't worked on Application development, but can tell for sure that as it is based on Linux, so knowing Linux will help you definitely as in tweaking and optimizing your applications.

But, answer to your question is NO. The tools used for knowing the parameters are available on Windows and adb shell provides quite a lot of information. So you can develop and optimize on Windows system.

And, answer to your last question is YES, if and only if you are working on underlying linux framework which is true for your case as you will be able to understand better that how interfacing happens, how is udev useful and how are parameters passed through sysfs.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your taste and liking. Whichever platform you are more comfortable with. There is nothing in Linux regarding android development which is not possible in Windows. Though if you have never used Linux environment then stick with Windows to keep things simple.

Comment: I do strongly suggest trying both, though. When I switched from Windows to Linux when I was teaching myself Java, my productivity seemingly doubled overnight, and that was *before* I got used to the new tools. 6 years later, I'm *still* finding things about Linux that make my life easier.

Answer (score 2):

I use Linux and OSX for Android development. There are numerous tools and programs that help in the development and Android Studio is faster on Linux/OSX.

And also there are no problems with the usb drivers of the devices...

Comment: Opinion, and not factual.  I have continual problems with various of my devices on both Linux and OSX.  OSX is also significantly slower for me than Windows.  Mind you, it is a Mac Mini which has always been poor, especially since Apple started "upgrading" it with "better" versions of OSX.

Comment: You have continual problems with various devices? What are the brands and models of them? I use Arch Linux with 4GB of RAM and it runs smoothly ...

Comment: On Windows, My Eclipse Bundle crashed twice. The R.java gets deleted automatically. So I'm thinking to switch it to Linux. Thanks for Answer.

Comment: HTC Desire, Galaxy Ace, Nexus 7 and a Chinese clone I bought for testing with 2 sims.  Mind you, the last one keeps getting forgotten in Windows too.  Windows does best, OSX next, Linux really struggles - Ubuntu Salamander.  Whatever, I am not a "fan" of any of them, they are just tools, my point was reacting to an opinionated expression which is not factual - Android Studio is faster on Linux/OSX - it is not, it's quicker on Windows for me than on Linux on the same dual boot PC and neither is the comment on USB.

Comment: @zackygaurav  Unfortunately, Eclipse is riddled with bugs.  The R.java problem is an Eclipse issue which you will get on any OS.  If you have a choice, go with Android Studio.

Comment: @zackygaurav Try the Android Studio ;)

Comment: @Simon Thanks Buddy for suggestion. Downloading Android Studio :)