# Is Linux a common environment for Android developers?

Tags: android, linux, device-driver

I am asking this because apparently few devices have support for Linux. My device(Asus) doesn't have USB driver for Linux and Google USB driver is not compatible as well. Which brings me to the emulator. Is it a way to go? Or should I move to Windows?

Comment: Nexus devices work without any problems on Ubuntu. Furthermore, there's always [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)

Comment: If you're going to do any serious work with the NDK I recommend Linux, just because build scripts etc work so much easier with it. Otherwise Windows or iOS should be fine. I have a Nexus 7 tablet (Asus/Google) and never had any problems connecting it via USB to Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @IvanLebediev: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit: yes, that's reasonable to me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most smartphone OEMs' have developed drivers for Mac OS X and Windows, and have excluded Linux. Not only that, but Intel x86 virtualization (which makes your emulator as fast as a real device) works only on Windows, not Linux. However, in Linux you have a kernel module known as `kvm` that plays the role of HAXM on Windows. And `kvm` works with both Intel **AND** AMD.

In light of this, you could consider Windows to ease the process of learning Android software development, or even better, use OS X, as it will also allow you to do iOS development (which is not possible on Windows). Moreover, OS X downloads smartphone drivers automatically when you plug the phone in, while on Windows you have to search for drivers on the web.

**Further considerations:**

- All `Nexus` devices work on Ubuntu Linux without hassles.
- Many developers who work with NDK prefer using Linux as its easy to work with the NDK tools in a Linux environment, i.e. no need to use Cygwin / MinGW.

**See also:**

**1.** [**Which is the best platform to develop Android apps: Windows, MacOS or Linux?**](http://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-platform-to-develop-Android-apps-Windows-MacOS-or-Linux)

**2.** [**Does using Linux OS matter while developing Android apps?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077652/does-using-linux-os-matter-while-developing-android-apps)

Comment: Intel HAXM works only on Windows and OSX, but that's because on Linux there is already a built-in kernel module that does the same task: kvm. and kvm works with both AMD and Intel CPUs. 

OEM Android drivers shouldn't be even needed on Linux. Even on Windows, you can almost always force the Google USB driver.